# Error: Field has an incomplete type

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

quaternion.h:15: error: field ‘v’ has incomplete type

Hi! I am stuck on an error that I cannot seem to solve.

Below is my code:

```
#ifndef QUATERNION_H
#define QUATERNION_H

#include "vec3.h"

class Vec3;

class Quaternion
{

public:

 Quaternion(Vec3 v);

 Quaternion(double w, Vec3 v);

 Vec3 v; <--------------------------This is where the error is :(

 double scalar;



 Quaternion operator *(Quaternion s);

 Quaternion conjugate();

};



#endif
```

My Vec.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef VEC3_H

#define VEC3_H



#include "point.h"

#include "quaternion.h"

#include <math.h>

class Quaternion;


class Vec3

{

 friend ofstream& operator <<(ofstream& output, const Vec3& p);

 friend ifstream& operator >>(ifstream& input, Vec3& p);



 public: 

 Vec3();

 Vec3(double _x, double _y);

 Vec3(double _x, double _y, double _z);



 double x,y,z;



 //Operators

 Vec3 operator -(Vec3 a) const;

 Vec3 operator /(double s) const;

 Vec3 operator *(double s) const;

 Vec3 operator *(Quaternion q) const;



 // Used to do vector Vec3 addition

 Vec3 operator +(Vec3 a) const;

 Point operator +(Point a) const;



 Vec3& operator =(Point a);



 Vec3 crossProduct(Vec3 v1); // Itself cross v1

 double dotProduct(Vec3 v);

 double length();

 void normalize();


};



#endif
```

Thanks for the help again =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you have circular inclusion of two header files: `vec3.h` and `quaternion.h`. Include guards will make sure that each header is included only once. One of them will be included first, the other - second. In your case `quaternion.h` is included first, meaning that `Vec3` becomes an incomplete type in it. This is what the compiler is telling you.

Since you are trying to use `Vec3` object as an immediate member of `Quaternion` object, you absolutely need `Vec3` to be a complete type. The `quaternion.h` header must include `vec3.h` header. The

```
class Vec3;
```

declaration achieves absolutely nothing in `quaternion.h`, so you can just remove it.

Given the above, it follows that `vec3.h` *cannot* include `quaternion.h`, or you'll end up with circular inclusion, which never achieves anything. Remove the inclusion of `quaternion.h` from `vec3.h`. Keep the

```
class Quaternion;
```

declaration in `vec3.h` and see if it works that way.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is mutual inclusion of the `.h`. The compiler knows the types, but at some point they are incomplete. My advice would be to just forward declare `Quarternion` in the file `vec3.h`, but NOT include `quaternion.h`.

Then, `quaternion.h` can include `vec3.h` and everything will compile. Also, as JaredPar suggested, remove the forward declaration of `Vec3` in `quaternion.h`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your files are include'ing eachother where there's no circular dependency. vec3 should not include quaternion then everything 'll be alright.

now the error the compiler gave is because you predeclared vec3 but the full definition is not read if vec3 is included:

vecr3.h --> include quaternion
quaternion.h --> include vec3 , but include-guards so nothing happens
quaternion.h --> predeclare Vec3,
quaternion.h --> try to use vec3 //fail
vec3.h --> actually declare vec3

the only correct order is first vec3 include and only THEN the quaternion include.